# Rectified image: interpolate missing points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image that I try to rotate around an x, y and z axis (rectification). This works fine, but I loose a lot of data. This is the script I use:

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
# import dateutil
# import pyparsing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import sys
from scipy import *
import Image
import matrotation as rmat
import math
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# set variable with location of files
working_dir = 'C:\Users\Yorian\Desktop\TU\Stage Shore\python_files\Rectification'
sys.path.append(working_dir)

# C is 3x1 matrix met (Xc, Yc, Zc).transpose()
# neem voor nu: C is nulvector
C = np.zeros((3,1), dtype='float32')

# 3x3 Identity matrix
I = np.identity(3)

# k matrix 3x3, LOAD the center pixel automatically as the point to rate around
K = np.array([[1.49661077e+04, -4.57744650e-13, 0.0],
             [0.0, -1.49661077e+04, 0.0],
             [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])

# rotatie matrix 1 (3x3) 0 graden om zowel x, y als z as
R1 = rmat.getR(25.0, 45.0, 0.0)

# [I|-C] (Zie Sierds paper) = 
I_extended = np.hstack((I,C))

# P = K*R*I
P1 = K.dot(R1).dot(I_extended)

# rotatie matrix 2
R2 = rmat.getR(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
P2 = K.dot(R2).dot(I_extended)

# Homography Matrix = H = P_rect * pinv(P) => P2 * pinv(P1)
H = P2.dot(np.linalg.pinv(P1))

# do image transform: x_uv_new = H * x_uv_original

# load image and convert it to grayscale (L)
img = Image.open('c5.jpg').convert('L')

# img.show()
img_array = np.array(img)

height = img_array.shape[0]
width = img_array.shape[1]

U, V = np.meshgrid(range(img_array.shape[1]),
                   range(img_array.shape[0]))
UV = np.vstack((U.flatten(),
                V.flatten())).T
UV_warped = cv2.perspectiveTransform(np.array([UV]).astype(np.float32), H)

UV_warped = UV_warped[0]
UV_warped = UV_warped.astype(np.int)

x_translation = min(UV_warped[:,0])
y_translation = min(UV_warped[:,1])

new_width = np.amax(UV_warped[:,0])-np.amin(UV_warped[:,0])
new_height = np.amax(UV_warped[:,1])-np.amin(UV_warped[:,1])
# new_img_2 = cv2.warpPerspective(img_array, H, (new_height+1, new_width+1))

UV_warped[:,0] = UV_warped[:,0] - int(x_translation)
UV_warped[:,1] = UV_warped[:,1] - int(y_translation)

# create box for image
new_img = np.zeros((new_height+1, new_width+1)) # 0 = black 255 - white background

for uv_pix, UV_warped_pix in zip(UV, UV_warped):
    x_orig = uv_pix[0] # x in origineel
    y_orig = uv_pix[1] # y in origineel
    color = img_array[y_orig, x_orig]

    x_new = UV_warped_pix[0] # new x
    y_new = UV_warped_pix[1] # new y
    new_img[y_new, x_new] = np.array(color)


img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(new_img))
img.save("testje.jpg")
```

This works fine. However I miss a lot of information. The larger the rotations the more information I loose. To get more information back I want to: interpolate the missing points. I tried to do this using grid(), but it returns an array that looks like this:
[nan]

The code for this:

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
# import dateutil
# import pyparsing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import sys
from scipy import *
import Image
import matrotation as rmat
import math
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# set variable with location of files
working_dir = 'C:\Users\Yorian\Desktop\TU\Stage Shore\python_files\Rectification'
sys.path.append(working_dir)

# C is 3x1 matrix met (Xc, Yc, Zc).transpose()
# neem voor nu: C is nulvector
C = np.zeros((3,1), dtype='float32')

# 3x3 Identity matrix
I = np.identity(3)

# k matrix 3x3, LOAD the center pixel automatically as the point to rate around
K = np.array([[1.49661077e+04, -4.57744650e-13, 0.0],
             [0.0, -1.49661077e+04, 0.0],
             [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])

# rotatie matrix 1 (3x3) 0 graden om zowel x, y als z as
R1 = rmat.getR(25.0, 45.0, 0.0)

# [I|-C] (Zie Sierds paper) = 
I_extended = np.hstack((I,C))

# P = K*R*I
P1 = K.dot(R1).dot(I_extended)

# rotatie matrix 2
R2 = rmat.getR(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
P2 = K.dot(R2).dot(I_extended)

# Homography Matrix = H = P_rect * pinv(P) => P2 * pinv(P1)
H = P2.dot(np.linalg.pinv(P1))

# do image transform: x_uv_new = H * x_uv_original

# load image and convert it to grayscale (L)
img = Image.open('c5.jpg').convert('L')

# img.show()
img_array = np.array(img)

height = img_array.shape[0]
width = img_array.shape[1]

U, V = np.meshgrid(range(img_array.shape[1]),
                   range(img_array.shape[0]))
UV = np.vstack((U.flatten(),
                V.flatten())).T
UV_warped = cv2.perspectiveTransform(np.array([UV]).astype(np.float32), H)

UV_warped = UV_warped[0]
UV_warped = UV_warped.astype(np.int)

x_translation = min(UV_warped[:,0])
y_translation = min(UV_warped[:,1])

new_width = np.amax(UV_warped[:,0])-np.amin(UV_warped[:,0])
new_height = np.amax(UV_warped[:,1])-np.amin(UV_warped[:,1])

UV_warped[:,0] = UV_warped[:,0] - int(x_translation)
UV_warped[:,1] = UV_warped[:,1] - int(y_translation)

# create box for image
data = np.zeros((len(UV_warped),1))

for i, uv_pix in enumerate(UV):
    data[i,0] = img_array[uv_pix[1], uv_pix[0]]

grid = griddata(UV_warped, data, (new_width+1, new_height+1), method='linear')
```

Can anybody help me to get an image from this that is interpolated?

BTW: I used the function `warpPerspective` as someone has told me, but this stretches the image but doesn't "rotate" it.

I also looked at `cv2.inpaint()` but can't get that to work either. I found this: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_inpainting/py_inpainting.html but that plots it. I want to make an image of it.

EDIT:

The code I used to do this with `warpTransform`:

```
#Importing modules
import json
import urllib2
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy import *
import Image

# data is now a dictionairy containing list with dictionairies with the x, y, z, U, V
# example:
# data[cameraID][listnumber] = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z, 'U': U, 'V': V}

T = {} # H is a list of Translation matrices, one for each camera

for cam in data:
    if len(cam) > 4:
        xyz_ar = np.array([[data[cam][0]['x'], data[cam][0]['y']],
                           [data[cam][1]['x'], data[cam][1]['y']],
                           [data[cam][2]['x'], data[cam][2]['y']],
                           [data[cam][3]['x'], data[cam][3]['y']]],np.float32)

        UV_ar = np.array([[data[cam][0]['U'], data[cam][0]['V']],
                          [data[cam][1]['U'], data[cam][1]['V']],
                          [data[cam][2]['U'], data[cam][2]['V']],
                          [data[cam][3]['U'], data[cam][3]['V']]], np.float32)

        T[cam] = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(UV_ar, xyz_ar)
    else:
        print('niet genoeg meetpunten voor de camera')

# load image
img = cv2.imread('c5.jpg')
rows, cols, channels = img.shape

# warp voor camera 5
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, T[u'KDXX05C'], (rows, cols))
new_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(dst))
new_img.save('testje.jpg')
```

Comment: Hello again, I think it was me who suggested the use of `warpPerspective` :) Can you explain _clearly_ what you mean by "rotation" of the image ? Because an image is always 2D, so applying a 3D rotation to it causes it to stretch.

Comment: Yes, it was. With yout help I got it to work, but the image warped very strangely. Maybe something is wrong in my code, but this is what I did (can't comment such long pieces of code, so editted my original post)

Comment: Apart from the fact that you miss a lot of information in your final image, does the homography `H` seem to correctly transform the image ?

Comment: Yes it does. The image looks fine. Changing the R1 (or R2) I can manually rotate the image around the three axis and this works fine

Answer (score 1):

I am still convinced that `warpPerspective` does exactly what you want (*jedi mind trick*). Seriously, it should do in one line what you are trying to achieve with the `meshgrid`, `vstack` and `griddata`.

Can you try the following code ? (I am not familiar with Python, so this might require some adjustements) :

```
# load image and convert it to grayscale (L)
img = cv2.imread('c5.jpg')
rows, cols, channels = img.shape
# img.show()

# Homography Matrix = H = P_rect * pinv(P) => P2 * pinv(P1)
H = P2.dot(np.linalg.pinv(P1))

cv2.warpPerspective(img, H, (rows, cols), dst, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
new_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(dst))
new_img.save('testje.jpg')
```

where `H` is the exact same matrix as you use in the first code sample you gave.

Comment: If I do this I get an empty image (white or black depending on the array I use for dst (apparently I needed to set it first))
My code

# load image and convert it to grayscale (L)
img = cv2.imread('c5.jpg')
rows, cols, channels = img.shape
# img.show()

# Homography Matrix = H = P_rect * pinv(P) => P2 * pinv(P1)
H = P2.dot(np.linalg.pinv(P1))

dst = np.ones((2000,2000))*255 # white background
cv2.warpPerspective(img, H, (rows, cols), dst, cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
new_img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(dst))
new_img.save('testje.jpg')

Comment: If I give you an example image (or all 6 that I want to use in the panorama) and an example output panorama (stitched and rectified) that this helps?

Comment: Not so much because my problem is the coding in python and also your convention with `H` and the two images. `P1` is the camera matrix of `img`, right ? If you add `cv2.INTER_LINEAR` as in my edit, is it better ?

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't. However, instead of working with a calculated homography I could also work with measures points in the real world if that is easier (or better)

Comment: @Yorian OK, one last try, can you check the result if you remove `cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP`, as in my edit?

Comment: Still nothing. If you don't mind, I can send you all my files (the tests I have) and photo's (I have the "source" photo's and a stitched and rectified panorama as it should become.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48397/discussion-between-yorian-and-aldurdisciple)

Answer (score 1):

The third argument of griddata is a (M,D) shaped array of locations that need interpolation (D=2 here). You are inputting a tuple of (width, height), so that is probably why you get a [nan] array.